# How do I get the silverlight view page name and querstring from silverlight code behind?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0, query-string

VS2010 w/Ria Services & SL4.

I already have my SL app loaded in the browser.

User clicks around to different view pages and I would like to store their current location in a list of "recently visited pages".

To do that, I need to store the view page + any existing querystring key/values.

Ex:  here is a real page in my sl app:
http://localhost:52878/Default.aspx#/DocSearchShell?CM-Origination

I don't care about anything before the # sign - there are a million ways on google to get the http: // localhost:52878/Default.aspx uri from sl.

What I *DO* want is the **"DocSearchShell?CM-Origination"** portion of the querystring - that is what I want to capture and store for the "recently visited pages"

How do I do this from sl4 (.NET 4) code-behind?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the browser's own history function not provide this feature for you?

Comment: I can access "DocSearchShell?CM-Origination" portion of the querystring if I use the built in SL4 navigation:  private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e){string myPage = e.Uri.ToString()}  But I would really like to know how to get to it from outside that event method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // The answer is this:
        // e.Uri.OriginalString;
    }
```

Comment: That's the only way I've found to do it. Would be nice to find out how to do it outside of the OnNavigatedTo method though.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the part of query string after "#" symbol via `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark`.
It works from any part of SL application.